# WCF Service Programatic NetTcpBinding vs. Web Config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

Is there an difference in calling my WCF service these two approaches?

1) programmatic binding:

```
var xml = "my xml string";
var ep = new EndpointAddress("http://myendpoint");
xml = new Proxy.ServiceClient(new NetTcpBinding(), ep).getNewXML(new Proxy.CallContext(), xml);
```

2) web config configuration:

```
var xml = "my xml string";
xml = new Proxy.ServiceClient().getNewXML(new Proxy.CallContext(), xml);
```

Corresponding web config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_SCSService">
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="myendpoint"
       binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_SCSService"
       contract="SCSProxy.SCSService" name="NetTcpBinding_SCSService">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```